# When using kotlinx.html's DSL to create HTML, (how) is it possible to refer to nested elements?

Tags: kotlin-js, kotlinx-html

I'm using kotlinx.html's DSL to create HTML, and I need references to some of the elements created (to refer to them in event handlers etc.). However, while the functions used directly within the block passed to `Node.append` do return references to the elements they create, it seems similar functions called within them to create nested elements do not.

Example code:

```kotlin
fun Node.appendElements() {
    append {
        val outer = div { // works as expected
            val inner = div {} // does not work
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `outer` indeed refers to the newly created and appended outer `div` created directly in the `append` block (this is basically the scenario of [When using kotlinx.html's DSL to create HTML, (how) is it possible to refer to the created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72355092/when-using-kotlinx-htmls-dsl-to-create-html-how-is-it-possible-to-refer-to-t)), but the `div` called within that `div` (in the nested block, not directly in the `append`) returns `Unit`, so that same (or at least very similar) solution doesn't work for the inner `div` (or generally for nested elements created not directly in the `append` block, but within blocks used to create outer elements).

I ended up writing a much more cumbersome code, similar to the following:

```kotlin
fun Node.appendElements() {
    append {
        val outer = div {}
        outer.append {
            val inner = div {}
        }
    }
}
```

That works, but is much less elegant. Is there any better / more idiomatic way to achieve this?